# Updating a label from a thread in Perl

Tags: linux, multithreading, perl

I'm using perl on a linux box, and I have 2 devices - a pc(the linux box) and a router/dsl-thingy - on my local net at ip addresses 192.168.1.1 & 192.168.1.2 and am trying to list or show the progress of pinging such + a test of 8 other none existing devices, with the below code, but am having troubles with my StatusLabel updating, any help...

```
for($i=1;$i<=10;++$i) { # --- $i<$VarClients --- 254
my $thr_List = ("ping$i");
$thr_List = threads->create(\&pingingthreads, "$i");
} 

sub pingingthreads{

     my @pingpong = ping("$localAddress$i", '-c 1', '-i .2'); # -i may not count for much?
     print "Pinging: $localAddress$i\n"; # output goes from address1 - address10 ok

     $StatusLabel = "Pinging: $localAddress$i";  # only the last responding one(device) seems to be shown in my statuslabel?!
     $val = ($val + 10); # 0.392156863
     print "$val\% done...\n"; # goes to 100% for me ok

    # $indicatorbar->value( $val ); # I have a ProgressBar and it gets stuck on 20% also

    if ($val == 100){$val = 0;
    } # reset after scanning
    # then after the last ping, update the statusLable:
        #my @ParamList = ('something', 'testing', 7, 8, 9);
        #$thr5 = threads->create(\&updateStatusLable, @ParamList); # starting a thread within a thread ???

# ping response text...
for( @pingpong ) { # need to do something for none responding clients & any time laps/ping latency..., or *** ???
$pong=$_; 
chop ($pong);           # Get rid of the trailling \n   ??
if ($pong =~ m/1 packets transmitted, 1 received, 0% packet loss/) {   
    push(@boxs, "$localAddress$i");
} else{
# see the other lines from the ping's output
# print "$pong\n";
}
}
}
# For $localAddress$i icmp_seq=1 Destination Host Unreachable ???

--------------------- # StatusBar/progress label & bar ----------------
my $sb = $main->StatusBar();        
$sb->addLabel( -textvariable => \$StatusLabel,
    -relief => 'flat',
    -font => $font, 
    -foreground => "$statusbartextColour",
    );


my $indicatorbar = $sb->ProgressBar( -padx=>2, -pady=>2, -borderwidth=>2,
          -troughcolor=>"$Colour2", 
        -colors=>[ 0, "$indicatorcolour" ],
          -length=>106, 
        -relief => 'flat',
        -value => "$val",
         )->pack;

  # $val = 0;
  # $indicatorbar->value( $val );

=====================================
my $StatusLabel :shared = ();
my $val :shared = (0); # var for progress bar value
```

I have uploaded my full code here (http://cid-99cdb89630050fff.office.live.com/browse.aspx/.Public) if needed, its in the Boxy.zip...

Comment: Welcome to SO. SO is not a code factory. You need to ask specific questions and you will get specific answers.

Comment: Sorry if the above is not right, my question put differently is... how do I update a label from a thread in Perl. I was using the above just to show where I am(just playing about).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't. GUI frameworks tend to be not threadsafe. You communicate the info to the thread in which the GUI is run instead. [Example](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=918667)

Answer (score 3):

<strike>By default data in Perl threads are *private*; updates to a variable in one thread will not change the value of that variable in other threads (or in the main thread). You will want to declare `$val` as a shared variable.
See [`threads::shared`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?threads%3a%3ashared).</strike>

I see you have declared `$val` as shared at the bottom of the script, so I didn't see it until it was too late. Not coincidentally, the Perl interpreter is also not going to see that declaration until it is too late. The top 95% of your program is manipulating the global, thread-private variable `$var` and not the lexical, shared `$var` you declare at the end of your script. Move this declaration to the top of the script.

Putting `use strict` at the top of your program would have caught this and saved you minutes, if not hours, of grief.

Answer (score 0):

First sorry for replying here, but have lost my cookie or the ability to reply and edit etc...

Thanks ikegami, I will have to play with the example for a while to see if I can work things out and mix it into what I'm doing... but on first sight, looks just right...  Thanks very much.

I was able to update the $StatusLabel using:

```
# in 3 seconds maybe do a fade to: Ready...
my @ParamList = ('ping', 'testing', 4, 5, 6);
$thr2 = threads->create(\&updateStatusLable, @ParamList);

sub updateStatusLable {
# should probably check if threads are running already first???
# and if so ***/*** them ???

my @InboundParameters = @_;
my $tid = threads->tid();
# my $thr_object = threads->self(); # Get a thread's object
# print("This is a new thread\($tid\)... and I am counting to 3...\n");
sleep(3);
    $StatusLabel = "Ready..."; # print "Am now trying to change the status bar's label to \"Ready...\"\n";
# try updating better/smoother... My main window needs "focus and a mouse move" I think
    # for the new text to appear...

   # print('Recieved the parameters:  ', join(', ', @InboundParameters), ".\n" );
   # $returnedvalue = "the thread should return this...";
   # return($returnedvalue); # try returning any value just to test/see how...
}
```

but will try your method... Thanks again.